# Tenant not vacating property(GERMANY)

Tags: contract-law, rental-property, germany

-See below for German version-

A tenant's fixed term rental contract has expired, yet on the first day after the expiration, when keys were supposed to be returned, the tenant has not made any efforts to vacate the property.
Under German Law, this means that the contract automatically gety extended indefinetely, unless either party objects and notifies the other party of this extension either in the contract or within two weeks of the tenant failing to vacate.

**How does the landlord best object to this extension, in the case where this did not already occur in the contract?**

Specifically, would a writing delivered by registered mail be enough to object?

Can the landlord then immediately file an action for eviction with the local court? Or does the two-week period first need to pass?

What happens if the tenant suddenly decides to vacate the property? An action of eviction needs to be pre-paid by the landlord. Is the tenant then liable to cover these expenses plus any lawyer expenses?

Many thanks!

---

Ein Mieter hat es versäumt eine Wohnung nach Ablauf eines befristeten Mietvertrags zu räumen. Der Vermieter hat dies am ersten Tag nach dem Ende des Vertrags erfahren. Nun tritt eine stillschweigende Mietverlängerung in Kraft, welcher einer der beiden Parteien binnen zwei Wochen widersprechen kann.

Wie geschieht dieser Widerspruch am besten?

Ist ein Einschreiben an den Mieter genug um in über einen Widerspruch zu informieren?

Kann der Vermieter dann unmittelbar Räumungsklage einreichen, oder erst nach Verstreichen des zweiwöchigen Zeitraums?

Wenn der Mieter sich nun doch dazu entscheidet auszuziehen, eine Räumungsklage aber jedoch schon eingereicht wurde, muss der Mieter die Kosten für diese Räumungsklage samt Anwaltskosten tragen?

Vielen Dank

Comment: Simple answer: Get a lawyer. It takes ages to get the tenant out. It takes longer to get the tenant out if you make any mistakes.

Comment: Many thanks. I've already contacted a lawyer but that will take some days, too. I was hoping someone with experience in this could help speed things up...